# Insert a date with format of mysql date as yyyy-mm-dd in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, format

I am using Laravel eloquent and I have a model with two date fields with date type in mysql. My date value is `dd/mm/yyyy`.  How can I insert a date with format of mysql date as `yyyy-mm-dd`.
My model

```
class Issue extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'issue';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ACC_NO';
    protected $keyType = 'String';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $dates= ['issue_date', 'due_date'];

    public function setIssue_DateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['issue_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value) );
    }

    public function setDue_DateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['due_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value) );
    }

    public function getIssue_DateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
    }

    public function getDue_DateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
    }

}
```

**My table creation of issue table is**

```
if (($handle = fopen(public_path().'/storage/'.$issueName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {    
        $issue_data = new Issue();
        $issue_data->MEM_NO = $data[0];
        $issue_data->ACC_NO = $data[1];
        $issue_data->issue_date = $data[2];
        $issue_data->due_date = $data[3];
        $issue_data->MEM_NAME = $data[4];
        $issue_data->TITLE = $data[5];
        $issue_data->AUTHOR = $data[6];
        $issue_data->RENEWS = $data[7];
        $issue_data->save();
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

**My sample data from csv file**

```
1633|00003|02/01/2018|07/02/2018|   ASISH    |a|Narayan|0
1641|00004|04/01/2018|07/02/2018|AMALKRISHNAN|b|Narayan|0
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the code inside accessors and mutators you've shown is working. But you're using the wrong names. Rename these mutators and accessors:

```
setIssue_DateAttribute
setDue_DateAttribute
getIssue_DateAttribute
getDue_DateAttribute
```

To:

```
setIssueDateAttribute
setDueDateAttribute
getIssueDateAttribute
getDueDateAttribute
```

Comment: You pointed out exactly. Greatful to you Sir. always my mind going through created_at variable in the mutator setting of the documentaion. Thats why underscore came. Its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
     $this->attributes['due_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value) );
```

To:

```
     $this->attributes['due_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/Y', $value)->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got your question right: you want to store the issue_date and due_date as strings instead of timestamp in the database?

You are casting issue_date and due_date as timestamps via the `protected $dates` array in your model. I think you should leave that off if you just want to store dates as a string the DB.

For example:
Your DB then contains issue_date as '2018-06-01' which you can convert to a timestamp using Carbon when needed.

However, I would always store dates as a timestamp and convert them to string in my application when needed.